# S3 event Multiple prefix on AWS Lambda function using Serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to add trigger event on a Lambda function on an already existing bucket and for that I am using below configuration where my bucket `test` is already existing on S3.

I have added below plugins to serverless.yml

plugins:

```
  serverless-plugin-existing-s3
```

Config:

```
functions:
  someFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - existingS3:
          bucket: Test
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: ds/of/pl/work/loc/
            - suffix: .json
```

My Bucket Structure is:

```
Test/ds/of/pl/work/loc/
Test/ds/mk/pl/work/loc/
Test/ds/gg/pl/work/loc/
```

Json object with `test_loc_timsetamp.json` will get created.

```
Test/ds/of/pl/work/rou/
Test/ds/mk/pl/work/rou/
Test/ds/gg/pl/work/rou/
```

Json object with `test_rou_timsetamp.json` will get created.

Now, I wanted to configure - multiple event rule (any json object created in above path) should trigger one single lambda.

That is any `loc` file created in three folders ending with loc/ to be triggered to run a loc lambda.

That is any `rou` file created in three folders ending with rou/ to be triggered to run a rou lambda.

Comment: not get your question. If you remove the `prefix`, it will trigger the event (the lambda function) every time, when there is a new json file created. Is that you are looking for?

Comment: @BMW added to the question

Comment: ic. you need the trigger with pattern as `Test/*/*/*/work/rou/` only, do you try it with `prefix`?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to give multiple event prefix.

Comment: Would  */* work ?

Comment: Did you find any solution @PrasannaNandakumar

Comment: Did you find any solution @ReazMurshed